# Detect Session Lock with QT

Tags: c++, qt, cross-platform

Is possible to detect if the session is locked (Windows, terminal linux/gnu and MacOSX) only using QT?

Must be something cross-platform. This is possible or I'll produce a condition for each platform?

Thanks

Comment: There’s no API in Qt for that. I also doubt it can be properly detected on all of them.

Comment: What session do you mean? Desktop browser session? The desktop login session itself, a database session or something else? Please clarify.

Comment: Windows, terminal linux and MacOSX, @LaszloPapp thanks :)